# Rexx Script (ssh automatically connection)

Tags: ssh, rexx

Hey dear Stackoverflow Community,

I'm looking for a simple rexx script to import the IP addresses from a text-data and paste these into the ssh credentials.

The first code below (for importing the first line) works fine:

`/* read"test.txt". */
line = LINEIN("test.txt")`

`CALL ZocTimeout 60
CALL ZocWaitForSeq "on"`

`/* Ausgabe Reihe. */
CALL ZocConnect SAY line`

Comment: What are you having trouble with, _specifically_?  The [Zoc documentation](https://www.emtec.com/downloads/zoc/rexx/docs/ZocRexxReference.pdf) seems clear both on Rexx and Zoc itself.

Comment: I think you may have an errant 'say' in the ZocConnect. Try `CALL zocConnect line`.